# permutations combinations for shirt

Tags: permutations, combinations

> How many different ways can 6 identical green shirts and 6
>   identical red shirts be distributed among 12 children such that each
>   child receives a shirt?

Now what will be the answer if they  get any number shirts?

EDIT :Actually I was supposed to solve the modified question, cause the first question can be solve by simply combination theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second problem is a typical urn problem as well. Distributing the 6 red shirts is like choosing from a urn of 12 people (with putting choosen people back to the urn) where the order does not matter. The number of ways to do that is given by the [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset_coefficient#Counting_multisets) coefficient:
$$\binom{n+k-1}{k}$$
Now $n=12$ and $k=6$ and you do this twice for each color, so the answer ist
$$\binom{12+6-1}{6}^2=\binom{17}{6}^2=153165376$$

Answer (score 1):

For the modified question, since each child can get 0, or 1, or 2, and so on red shirts, the number of ways the red shirts can be distributed is the coefficient of $x^6$ in

$$(1+x+x^2+\dots)^{12} = (1-x)^{-12}$$

Since the conditions are now so that the green and red shirts can be distributed independently, the total count is the square of this, which computes to $12376^2 = 153165376$